# Enumerating posts in Wordpress won't work twice

Tags: php, wordpress, side-effects

This method was posted by someone on the Wordpress forum to get the post "number" (1, 2, 3, 4, etc) from its ID (Which is not sequentially ordered). I modified it a bit to only query for slides.

```
function Get_Post_Number($postID){
    $temp_query = $wp_query;
    $postNumberQuery = new WP_Query(array(
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'post_type' => 'slide'));

    $counter = 0;
    $postCount = 0;
    if($postNumberQuery->have_posts()) :
        while ($postNumberQuery->have_posts()) : $postNumberQuery->the_post();
            if ($postID == get_the_ID()){
                $postCount = $counter;
            } else {
                $counter++;
            }
    endwhile; endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    $wp_query = $temp_query;
    return $postCount;
}
```

It works fine when called once, and will return the correct number.

```
Get_Post_Number(get_the_ID()) //Returns 3 (for instance)
```

But when called twice, it no longer works:

```
Get_Post_Number(get_the_ID()) //Returns 3 (for instance)
Get_Post_Number(get_the_ID()) //Returns 0 (wrong!)
```

This leads me to believe that the function has side-effects, but I'm not sure how to undo them. Wordpress says to call `wp_reset_query()` after you do your own "custom loop," but the function already does that.

What should I do?

Comment: Does it always return 0 when called multiple times, or other numbers as well?

Comment: @anthonygore Just 0.

Comment: `$postID == get_the_ID()` if this is true the $counter var will always be 0. echo both vars to test but id say thats whats happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the `wp_reset_query()` and it worked. (Even though Wordpress tells you to call that!?)